# RGB Tuples to RGB Integers

Tags: python

I was wondering how can I grab a color from a pixel as an RGB integer with conversion if needed. Also, how can I determine if a pixel is lighter or darker than another pixel by using the differences.

Comment: A pixel from where? What is the datastructure?

Comment: A tuple as seen in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
rgb_int = rgb_tuple[0] << 16 | rgb_tuple[1] << 8 | rgb_tuple[2]
```

Testing for lighter or darker is trickier. You should work with a single grayscale value for the lightness, then they are directly comparable. There are different ways to convert RGB to grayscale, this is the oldest and simplest:

```
gray = r * 0.299 + g * 0.587 + b * 0.114
```

Comment: So how can I determine if a pixel is lighter or darker than another pixel by using the differences.

Comment: Is there a way to extend this process with a four item tuple with an alpha value.

Comment: There's no way to add the alpha to the grayscale calculation, but it's easy to add it to the integer. Does it need to go into the upper bits?

Comment: I don't really understand the logic behind any of this, so I'm trusting you on this one.